# manual inputs embed in msi using wix

Tags: windows, wix, installation

I would like to install a third party executable that expects some user inputs on a user machine.To this aim, I would like to make the installation silent.

Is there a way to achive using wix?

Answer (score 1):

The most "correct" way would be to create a `Bundle` that used a `Chain` to install the `ExePackage` and your `MsiPackage`. You can control the inputs to the `ExePackage` via the `InstallCommand` attribute. The `InstallCommand` attribute can use `Variable`s from the `Bundle` by doing something like:

```
<ExePackage InstallCommand="[MyVariable] -someswitch"
            DetectCondition="DetectedThirdPartyInstalled"
            SourceFile="path\to\thirdparty.exe" />
```

If you really must try to install the executable during your .msi then you'll need to use a `CustomAction` and the `ExeCommand` attribute can pass parameters. That would look something like:

```
<CustomAction FileKey="FileIdForThirdPartyExe" ExeCommand="[MyProperty] -someswitch" />
```

Take a look in the WiX.chm for those key words for more other details.

Comment: thank you,the code snippet makes sense.
I am new to wix, it is much appreciated if you can provide an example or any link which can guide me